# Multi-selected option for quantity that updates Total value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I have prepared the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JHMq/1/) that ilustrates the core of the issue

The problem is as follow:
I have a list with products in a shop basket. Each product has options available for example colors and when the customer select a quantity for white color for example the js function:

```
function update_amounts(){
var sum = 0.0;
$('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function() {
var qty = $(this).find('.qty option:selected').val();     
var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
var amount = (qty*price);
sum+= amount;
$(this).find('.amount').text(''+ amount);
//alert(sum);
});
```

must update the total amount for the products. Function works fine but it calculates only for the first selected color quantity, but if the customer decides to order another 2 black items it will not calculate them. My question is how to make this function to sum all quantities from different colors and multiply them with the product Single price so I get a correct Total?
Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: it would be great if you share the html too.

Comment: html is shared in the jsfiddle please

Comment: common guys, are you all on the beach :)